# Checking Kangaroo word in python

Tags: string, python-3.x, loops, combinatorics

Kangaroo word refers to a word carrying another word within but without transposing any letters.For example, courage contains cog,cur,core etc. but not run,gen,gone.Given 2 string im trying to check if the first string is kangaroo word of the second.

Here is my code

```
import sys
s1=input().rstrip()
s1l=[]
for i in s1:
    s1l.append(i)
s2=input().rstrip()
s2l=[];sol=[]
for i in s2:
    s2l.append(i)
ls=len(s1l)
for i in range(ls):
    for j in range(ls):
        for k in range(ls):
            sol.append((s1[i]+s1[j]+s1[k]))
for i in sol: 
    if i==s2:
        print('s1 is a kangaroo word of s2')
        sys.exit()
print('s1 is Not a kangaroo word of s2')
```

But Im not able to get the desired output.For eg for s1=chariot and s2=rat my code shows true whereas the answer is false.Can someone please explain what mistake Ive made ?

Answer (score 1):

There're quite a few things you can do differently, besides your question, so I'm going to comment on a bunch of them.

However, your main problem is that you're looping `i`, `j`, and `k` over all of the characters, instead of limiting that `i < j < k` be always true.

```
import sys
s1=input().rstrip()
s1l=[]
for i in s1:
    s1l.append(i)
s2=input().rstrip()
s2l=[];sol=[]
for i in s2:
    s2l.append(i)
```

This code can be much more cleanly written like this:

```
import sys
s1=input().rstrip()
s2=input().rstrip()

s1l=[c for c in s1]
s2l=[c for c in s2]

sol=[]
```

This is much more Pythonic and clean. However, you never use `s2l`, so why do it at all?

```
import sys
s1=input().rstrip()
s2=input().rstrip()

s1l=[c for c in s1]
sol=[]
```

Even better. But you can actually index into a string without making it into a list. You never used `s1l` anyway, except for the length, which you could do with `s1`.

```
import sys
s1=input().rstrip()
s2=input().rstrip()
sol=[]

ls=len(s1)
for i in range(ls):
    for j in range(ls):
        for k in range(ls):
            sol.append((s1[i]+s1[j]+s1[k]))
```

This is where your main issue is. I'll first fix it the way you have it:

```
ls=len(s1)
for i in range(ls-2):
    for j in range(i+1, ls-1):
        for k in range(j+1, ls):
            sol.append((s1[i]+s1[j]+s1[k]))
```

However, why continue building a list of possible solutions (in `sol`) if you already know it's got a kangaroo word? Here's a better fix. Instead of this:

```
ls=len(s1)
for i in range(ls-2):
    for j in range(i+1, ls-1):
        for k in range(j+1, ls):
            sol.append((s1[i]+s1[j]+s1[k]))
for i in sol: 
    if i==s2:
        print('s1 is a kangaroo word of s2')
        sys.exit()
print('s1 is Not a kangaroo word of s2')
```

Do this:

```
ls=len(s1)
for i in range(ls-2):
    for j in range(i+1, ls-1):
        for k in range(j+1, ls):
            word = s1[i]+s1[j]+s1[k]
            if word == s2:
                print('s1 is a kangaroo word of s2')
                sys.exit()
print('s1 is Not a kangaroo word of s2')
```

**But...** this solution only finds sub-words of length 3, and is still rather cumbersome. To make it find all length sub-words, you'll have to be a little more careful...